# Add actions to list view on standard object

Tags: page-layout, search-layout, custom-actions

I have created a mass update action on products object.

I need to insert it on the List view for Search Layout for Classic but it only gives me the option to add buttons and not actions.

I inserted the action on the page layout and is not showing either.

Is there anything I can do to solve it, seeing that adding the action on list view would be the best way for me, I really don't know why it isn't appearing. -.-

Any ideas on what to do??

[image]

Comment: I was able to see the action that I have created in the available quick actions box.Can you please try again by referring the steps mentioned in this doc:https://www.simplysfdc.com/2018/03/salesforce-list-view-mass-action-in.html

Comment: Hi, Shirisha Pathuri

I was trying to do exactly it, but the issue is on Step 2 of the link.

It doesn't appear this list view for actions, only for buttons.

That's any way to make the object show this "List View Actions in Lightning Experience"????

Comment: I added the picture above so you can see.